# Looping through two lists

Tags: c#, .net, loops

Please pardon my idiocy I don't think my coffee has kicked in yet  :(

I am trying to loop through two lists and create an assignment based on a value for both lists. 
eg. 
List 1 is a list of folders I want to create 
List 2 is a list of hard drives with free space

I want to spread the folder creation across drives by the list count is not equal.

So I want to let's say for the first iteration in the folder list try drive 1 and if it has space and does not already have the folder create it. 
Then move to folder two and drive two - then folder three and drive three (if the total number of drives is 3) I want to move back to drive one for the next folder until all folders are created.

Can anyone help me with a sample of how to get there ?

Comment: So you are looking for recursion probably and not looping through two lists?

Comment: Can you post what you have so far so this is not too broad? You can see the guidelines to create a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: The problem is under-specified. What do you want to have happen if no drive has space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question I often consider is "how can I move the tricky mechanisms off to a type of their own".  In your case you want to have an enumeration of a list that starts over when it is done, but another way to think of that is to have a counter that wraps around when it gets to the top of a range.  So let's implement that:

```
struct WrappingCounter
{
    private int current;
    private int max;
    public WrappingCounter(int max) : this(0, max) {
        if (max <= 0) throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    private WrappingCounter(int current, int max)
    {
        this.current = current % max;
        this.max = max;
    }
    public static implicit operator int(WrappingCounter c) {
        return c.current;
    }
    public static WrappingCounter operator ++(WrappingCounter c) {
        return new WrappingCounter(c.current + 1, c.max);
    }
}
```

This code is also interesting in that it is an object lesson in how to write a correct `++` operator in C#.  Note that `++` **returns the incremented value**, unlike in C++.  It does not mutate `c`; it produces a *new* object that represents the incremented `c`. The compiler will take care of assigning it at the appropriate time.

Now that we have isolated the ugly mechanisms to their own type, the main algorithm now becomes much easier to read:

```
var dirs = new List<string> { "dir1", "dir2", "dir3" };
var drives = new List<string> { "drive1", "drive2" };
var c = new WrappingCounter(drives.Count);
foreach(var dir in dirs) {
    var drive = drives[c];
    c++;
    Console.WriteLine(dir + " " + drive);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough outline of an algorithm. It will match the first folder to the first drive, the second folder to the second drive, and so on. Unless there's not enough space. Then it will try subsequent drives (in a loop). Once space is found, it will resume iterating over drives after the last one found. For example:

folder_1 -> drive_a
folder_2 -> drive_b
folder_3 -> (skip drive_c) -> drive_d
folder_4 -> drive_e

etc

```
// You'll need to associate required space with each folder
public class FolderThing
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Size {get; set;}
}

// Each drive will need to track available free space
public class DriveThing
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int AvailableSpace {get; set;}
}

// Collection of folders, populate as required.
var foldersToAllocate = new List<FolderThing>();

// Collection of drives, populate as required.
var drivesToUse = new List<DriveThing>();

var numberOfDrives = drivesToUse.Count();
int nextDrive = 0;

foreach (var f in foldersToAllocate)
{
    // Track whether space could be allocated ...
    bool spaceFound = false;
    int tryCount = 0;

    // For loop, to exit early on success.
    // Try every available drive once, until space is found.
    for (tryCount=0; tryCount<numberOfDrives; tryCount++)
    {
        var drive = drivesToUse[(tryCount + nextDrive) % numberOfDrives];

        if (drive.AvailableSpace > f.Size)
        {
            // do the allocate thing
            // update space used for drive
            spaceFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Increment to the next drive after the previous one.
    nextDrive = (nextDrive + tryCount + 1) % numberOfDrives;

    if (spaceFound == false)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find enough free space");
    }

}
```